# Ddev update -> Migrating bind-mounted database in ~/.ddev to docker-volume mounted database

Tags: docker, updates, ddev

i have updated Ddev and Docker and now i get the following message:

"Migrating bind-mounted database in ~/.ddev to docker-volume mounted database"
"Failed to remove ddev project crazy-twins.de.development: Failed to start project xx to snapshot database: Failed to migrate db from bind-mounted db: failed t
o run migrate_file_to_volume.sh, err=container run failed with exit code 2 output="

How can i fix this?
How can i remove the database if necessary?

No container starts anymore.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can also just delete -/.ddev/crazy-twins (or whatever it is) and it won't try to migrate any more. You'll lose your db and have to re-import it though.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was following the steps to upgrade from version `1.0.0` to `1.2.0`, I followed the steps of the documentation: `remove the custom .yml`, `run ddev config` and here I made my mistake, the next step was `ddev start` and I ran `ddev restart` I realized how much 15 seconds maybe, and I stopped the process with `ctrl + c` and from that moment I broke the update process.

Never again could I start the process again.

What I realized in my case was that the process of updating ddev, creates a container to migrate the databases called as follows:

```
{nameYourProject}_migrate_volume
```

I could see it running `docker ps -a`

Apparently this volume got corrupted when I stopped the update process.

**The solution (in my case):**

I removed the migration container,

```
docker rm 3435 // use the hash number of the migration container
```

Then execute ddev start again and the update was executed without problem.

I could not execute the `docker container prune` command because it removes all the containers that you have created.

I hope someone serves you.

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. Cleaning up stopped docker containers with

```
docker container prune
```

before running ddev did the job for me. Hope this helps!